# Skip the "Unlock sim" window when booting

Tags: sim-unlocking

I use Keepass2Android to store my password, credentials and other sensitive information. For me it makes sense to use use it to store the PIN of my SIM card as well, so that I don't have to remember it.

But when I reboot my phone (moto g73) I get the window with the *unlock sim* form and I would like to skip this step and look up the SIM on my keepass and then unlock the SIM. But it seems that this is not possible, at least I cannot find any setting related to that. The only thing that I can find is to disable the SIM locking entirely but I want my sim to be locked. I just want to unlock it after I looked up the SIM on keepass.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Sim pins are 4 digit numeric combination if I'm correct. Just set it to something you'd remember. Why complicate things?

Comment: Because for a while I had more than one SIM at a time and I don't want to remember the PINs every time I change my SIM. That's why I want to use keepass.